Morphisms and relations
I need some help distinguishing these topics. I find them difficult to visualize, and researching them is also challenging, as there have been the occasional paradoxes…

Correspondences and Morphisms
Structures and (Pre)Categories

In summary,
How are morphisms related to correspondences?  Just answering this will clear up 90% of my confusion over the topic as I continue to introduce myself to it
If I make any mistakes in the wording, please correct me:
Relations are a subset of the Cartesian Product between Sets, (a set of ordered tuples).
Correspondences are sometimes referred to as a generalization of a binary relation… Commonly, the terms Binary Relation and Correspondence are synonyms, but why are they different for the mathematicians that draw a distinction?
Partial Order Relations are Reflexive, Antisymmetric, and Transitive.
Morphisms are naturally composable, which suggests that they ~might inherit some property of Transitivity.
To my understanding, Morphisms are not Relations (Relations are sets, while Morphisms map between a source and target),
Are the concepts utterly unrelated to each other?
I keep reading that Relations are Morphisms in different threads and wanted clarification. (Relations are morphisms in the category Rel).
What would we identify for the source and target if a relation is a morphism? Does that mean we can compose relations naturally?
If a relation is unrelated to a morphism, I still want to mention the concept of a Function because I have a follow-up…
Functions are relations, and functions are functors.
If relations are unrelated to morphisms, for which of the following does that change:

relations (are they morphisms?)
correspondences (are they morphisms?)
homomorphisms (are they relations?)
functors (are they relations?)
 Or are functions the first point of intersection?

Before I continue, I apologize for not understanding the topic. I’m an undergraduate, and I appreciate any guidance.
I don’t know the formal definition of a Mathematical Structure, but if I had to guess:
A Structure is a Class with a signature of relations.
Depending on how Morphisms and Relations are related to each other,
Does that affect how (Pre)categories are related to Classes of relations?
~ By precategory, I mean a category that does not require the id and associativity properties.
Would you argue that all Structures are Categories? (Assuming that maybe all relations were morphisms).
Researching these questions has led to a few paradoxes in the research. It doesn’t help that I don’t know the basics.
One paradox that baffles me is the “Membership Relation” concept. If Relations are sets, they have members and a membership relation, creating a circular paradox.
I appreciate your time; thank you very much!

You are trying to understand way too many different things at once. Slow down! What have you been reading and why?

You use the word "are" a lot in your question, and this is already something that needs to be discussed. In category theory this word "are" (or "is", and so forth) is subtle. It is subtle to say what exactly is meant by the claim that "X's are Y's" in a category-theoretic context.

Correspondences are sometimes referred to as a generalization of a binary relation… Commonly, the terms Binary Relation and Correspondence are synonyms, but for the mathematicians that draw a distinction,, why are they different?

In short, correspondences are not necessarily subsets. The term is used to mean several different related things, I think, but broadly a correspondence between two objects $X$ and $Y$ is a third object $C$ equipped with a morphism $C \to X \times Y$ which is not necessarily a monomorphism, meaning $C$ is not necessarily a subobject (the category-theoretic generalization of subsets) of the product.

To my understanding, Morphisms are not Relations, (Relations are sets, while Morphisms map between a source and target), Are the concepts completely unrelated from each other?

It's important to understand that "morphism" is an absurdly general term. The term can refer to any morphism in any category whatsoever. They are much, much more general than relations, but relations in particular "are" (or more precisely, can be thought of as) morphisms in a specific category called $\text{Rel}$, the category of relations.

If a relation is a morphism, then what would we identify for the source and target? Does that mean we can compose relations naturally?

Yes. If $R$ is a relation thought of as a subset of $X \times Y$, then we can think of its source as $X$ and its target as $Y$. The intuitive idea here is to think of $R$ as a "nondeterministic function" from $X$ to $Y$, which sends $x \in X$ to the set of all $y \in Y$ such that $xRy$.
This interpretation of relations as nondeterministic functions suggests a way to compose them, which formally works out to the following: if $R$ is a relation on $X \times Y$, and $S$ is a relation on $Y \times Z$, then the composite relation $S \circ R$ is the relation where $x(S \circ R)z$ iff there exists $y \in Y$ such that $xSy$ and $yRz$. In terms of the nondeterministic function idea this means that $S \circ R$ first applies $R$ to $x$ to get a set of possible values in $Y$, then applies $S$ to each of these possible values in $Y$ to get a further set of possible values in $Z$.

Functions are Relations

Be careful with this. It's more accurate to say that functions can be interpreted as particular relations, satisfying special conditions.

and also Functions are Functors.

I don't know what you mean by this. There's a degenerate sense in which functions are, technically, functors between discrete categories. But functors are a more general concept.

relations (are they morphisms?)

Yes, in the category $\text{Rel}$.

correspondences (are they morphisms?)

More precisely, one can write down categories of correspondences, where the morphisms are correspondences and correspondences can be composed by taking pullbacks.

homomorphisms (are they relations?)

This is an awkward question to give either a yes or a no answer to. Typically "homomorphism" is used to refer to a function between structured sets of some kind (e.g. groups) which preserves that structure. Since functions can be described as special kinds of relations, this means that homomorphisms can too. But this is not really a useful way to think about homomorphisms.

functors (are they relations?)

This is again an awkward question to give either a yes or a no answer to, because again, strictly speaking a functor is a certain kind of function (or rather pair of functions, on objects and on morphisms). Let's go with "basically no."

Or are functions the first point of intersection?

I don't know what you mean by this.

Depending on how Morphisms and Relations are related to each other, Does that affect how (Pre)categories are related to Classes of relations?

I don't know what you mean by this.

Would you argue that all Structures are Categories? (Assuming that maybe all relations were morphisms).

No, if anything it's the reverse: a category is a certain kind of (two-sorted) structure. Structures can be more general and don't have to look anything like categories.

One paradox that baffles me is the concept of a “Membership Relation”. If Relations are sets, then they have members, and a membership relation, creating a circular paradox.

This is a quite different question from the others and is more about how set-theoretic foundations work. The membership relation in set theory is not described as a relation-in-the-sense-of-a-subset-of-the-cartesian-product at all, because as you say that would be circular; we start in set theory with the membership relation, before we've defined either what a subset or what a cartesian product is.
Instead it is just directly axiomatized as a formal symbol $x \in y$ which is subject to certain rules for how it can be manipulated. If you want more details about this you can look up any introduction to set-theoretic foundations; maybe Halmos' Naive Set Theory would be a good place to start, I'm not sure.

I owe you a few ‘thank you’s for this response. First, thank you for clarifying the concept behind Membership. I appreciate you highlighting the concept of “are” and “is”; as I study these different topics, I have relied heavily on some kind of hierarchical structure relating these different topics,, Ill look into the notion of “are” as it is used by mathematicians. Next, I owe you a thank you for elaborating on the scope of relations and morphisms— I’m sorry for any confusion in the list portion: comparing functions to functors and other objects.

Part of my motivation for studying these concepts was to create more accurate data structures in computer science. I believe the standard library lacks completeness and accuracy,, and I also believe it is beneficial for me to understand these things to some extent. I just want to do better overall, and appreciate your time greatly. Thank you. I’ll keep studying!

@tylerbakeman: okay, from a computer science POV the subtlety in the use of "are" has to do with a phenomenon similar to type conversion. In mathematics there are many different type conversions in play, some of which are used implicitly without noting them. Sometimes "X's are Y's" refers to an implicit type conversion. But sometimes these type conversions are not unique and then we should really specify which one we're using rather than using this "are" language. Also sometimes, as above, a type conversion technically exists but is not very useful.

These things aren't strictly hierarchical in the same way that types aren't strictly hierarchical. There are many ways to convert types into other types and those ways don't necessarily organize into a hierarchy (in fact they organize into a category!). It's the same in mathematics.
